# Google App Engine: Missing required argument 'module[s]'

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

Google Web Toolkit 2.4.0 | Eclipse Version: Indigo Service Release 1 | Build id: 20110916-0149

**Project:** "guestbook" sample application present in appengine/demo folder

**Error:** Missing required argument 'module[s]'

**Background:** I used to build/compile apps in eclipse helios. After upgrading to new google app engine sdk and eclipse getting above error while running any non - GWT application. However a simple GWT application is running correctly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I finally found out the issue. When creating a new Google Web Application project, there are 2 options, Google Web Toolkit and Google App Engine which can be selected. I was selecting both so the project which was being created was a GWT project. So while running it was expecting a gwt module and related configuration file.

The solution was to not select "Google Web Toolkit" when creating a new Google Web Application Project.

Answer (score 5):

To disable Google Web Toolkit for your created project, just do like this:
1. select project, right click, and select "Property"
2. Toggle down "Google", select "Web Toolkit" tab, and uncheck "Use Google Web Toolkit". 
3. Delete your project in Run configuration. And run again. 
You will find it never asks for "modules" anymore.

Answer (score 2):

The missing module argument is the full name of your module, e.g. "com.google.gwt.sample.mail.Mail". Add it to the end of the argument in Run Configuration and the error should disappear.

[source here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit/iDRkGJ1vmdw)

Comment: sure thing I did though (you maybe got a downvote with no comment too) @Pablo Chvx